# how to use arrays in gekko optimizer for python

Tags: python, gekko

I tried to convert an example from `gekko` `python` optimizer by using the list, `array x[]` instead of variables `x1`..`x4`. This is the code which gives the result, but I think it is not correct

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
# Initialize Model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

#help(m)

#define parameter
eq = m.Param(value=40)

#initialize variables
x = [m.Var(value=1,lb=1,ub=5) for i in range(4)]
x[1].value=5
x[2].value=5

#Equations
m.Equation(np.prod([x[i] for i in range(0,4)])>=25)
m.Equation(np.sum([x[i]**2 for i in range(0,4)])==eq)

#Objective
m.Obj(x[0]*x[3]*(x[0]+x[1]+x[2])+x[2])

#Set global options
m.options.IMODE = 3 #steady state optimization

#Solve simulation
m.solve() # solve on public server

#Results
print('')
print('Results')
print('x1: ' + str(x[0].value))
print('x2: ' + str(x[1].value))
print('x3: ' + str(x[2].value))
print('x4: ' + str(x[3].value))
```

Please anyone could help me out how to use list, array of variables in `gekko`. This seems to me less elegant and I was wondering is there is a way of using Array() function instead of Var(). I can not figure out how and when we can use Array() function.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the m.Array GEKKO function to create Variable, Parameter, FV, MV, SV, or CV as 1D or multi-dimensional arrays. Here is an example of using m.Array to declare the variables. In subsequent steps, I define the initial guess and the bounds.

```
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO    
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Array(m.Var,(4))
# intial guess
ig = [1,5,5,1]
# lower bounds
i = 0
for xi in x:
    xi.value = ig[i]
    xi.lower = 1
    xi.upper = 5
    i += 1
#Equations
m.Equation(np.prod(x)>=25)
m.Equation(sum(x**2)==40)
#Objective
m.Obj(x[0]*x[3]*(x[0]+x[1]+x[2])+x[2])
m.solve()
print(x)
```

Here are the results:

```
The solution was found.

The final value of the objective function is    17.0140171270735     

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :   9.999999980209395E-003 sec
 Objective      :    17.0140171270735     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------

[[1.000000057] [4.74299963] [3.8211500283] [1.3794081795]]
```

Comment: I think I figured out now. Thank you.
Wish you good luck in developing gekko

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Let us know if we can develop new features that facilitate your application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I might miss some additional source of information regarding Gekko, but the first thing a potential user finds about Gekko is its Documentation and the very useful 18 Application Examples. I think that Documentation will be much better if the m.Array() is explained with few more sentences and maybe a single additional example using m.Array() in more details.

Best Regards,
Radovan

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Here is one example (Problem #3): https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html?highlight=array  Questions like yours are also very helpful on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me out to these examples. I think I've already examined them many times by expploring and experimenting with Gekko. One more question, if you do not mind. I excuse myself if that is already answered somewhere. Regarding the first example (System of linear equations) I tried and failed to give m.Equations([eq]) something like eq = np.dot(A,x) == b. How could one solve a large system of linear equations? Does m.Equations() even accepts a vector of boolean expression obtained by matrix manipulation (multiplication, inverting, transposing)?

Comment: I added a couple examples and a few new features to Gekko yesterday to help with large and sparse matrices. Please see https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/blob/master/examples/test_qobj_axb.py and https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/blob/master/examples/test_qobj_axb_sparse.py (for sparse matrices). The new features will be supported in the new release 0.2rc6 that should also be out today. It will be available with "pip install gekko==0.2rc6".

Comment: Additional matrix operation examples with linear programming (dense and sparse matrices) are available: https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/LinearProgramming  The `axb` and `state_space` functions are described in more detail in the documentation: https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html?highlight=axb#pre-built-objects

Answer (score 4):

This one will work as well.

```
#Equations
m.Equation(np.prod(np.asarray(x))>=25)
m.Equation(np.sum(np.asarray(x)**2)==eq)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of solving the system of linear equations and the example of using for loop for many equations.

```
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# Random 3x3
A = np.random.rand(3,3)
# Random 3x1
b = np.random.rand(3)
# Gekko array 3x1
x = m.Array(m.Var,(3))

# solve Ax = b
eqn = np.dot(A,x)
for i in range(3):
   m.Equation(eqn[i]==b[i])
m.solve(disp=False)
X = [x[i].value for i in range(3)]
print(X)
print(b)
print(np.dot(A,X))
```

with the the correct output. With the result X (np.dot(A,X)==b) - correct!

```
[[-0.45756768428], [1.0562541773], [0.10058435163]]
[0.64342498 0.34894335 0.5375324 ]
[[0.64342498]
[0.34894335]
[0.5375324 ]]
```

In the recent Gekko 0.2rc6 there is also introduced axb() function for linear programing. This might be the same problem solved with this function, but I am not sure how to get the correct result.

```
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# Random 3x3
A = np.random.rand(3,3)
# Random 3x1
b = np.random.rand(3)
# Gekko array 3x1
x = m.Array(m.Var,(3))

# solve Ax = b
m.axb(A,b,x=x)
m.solve(disp=False)
X = [x[i].value for i in range(3)]
print(X)
print(b)
print(np.dot(A,X))
```

but it seems I missed something because the output is not the solution??? With the result X (np.dot(A,X)==b) - is not correct!

```
[[0.2560342704], [0.7543346092], [-0.084190799732]]
[0.27262652 0.61028723 0.74616952]
[[0.4201021 ]
[0.5206979 ]
[0.39195592]]
```

Comment: Could you post this as a new question? I think I missed your answer that had another question.

Comment: Hello, I am not sure about the question. It might be the one about the m.axb() function. Here is the link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/67217773/5011402